# Why am I getting an error when trying to add the src attribute to an img tag using JavaScript within Colfusion?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion to connect to and execute methods from a Web Service. I store the contents of the returned xml string in to a ColdFusion array then I convert the ColdFusion array into a JavaScript array, so that I may populate the content of my HTML document.

My problem arises when trying to add a photo to a unordered list called "`agent_photo_list`". Specifically when I call the `.setAttribute` method. It seems to involve the `'src'` parameter. The JavaScript code works as I expect when it is not inside the `cfscript tag` and `WriteOutput` method. I have researched the problem, I haven't been able to find a reference that is sufficiently  similar. I am still having trouble understanding what my problem is. I have included my code below:

```
cfscript>
    WriteOutput('
    <script language = "JavaScript">
        var #ToScript(array, "jsArray")#
        var agent = jsArray[0];
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = agent.firstname + " " + agent.lastname;
        var imgurl = "_images/agentphoto.jpg";
        var node = document.createElement("LI");  
        var imgnode = (document.createElement("IMG"));
        imgnode.setAttribute('src', "imgurl");
        node.appendChild(imgnode);
        document.getElementById("agent_photo_list").appendChild(node);
    </script>
    ')
</cfscript>
```

I am using a jpg file located in my `_images` folder for testing purposes, I will later change it to `agent.photourl`.

The error I get is provided below:

> Invalid CFML construct found on line 117 at column 35.ColdFusion was
>   looking at the following text:<p>src</p><p>The CFML
>   compiler was processing:<ul><li>An expression beginning
>   with WriteOutput, on line 111, column 17.This message is usually
>   caused by a problem in the expressions structure.<li>A script
>   statement beginning with WriteOutput on line 111, column
>   17.<li>A cfscript tag beginning on line 102, column 10.</ul> The specific sequence of files included or processed is: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\webservice.cfm, line: 117

I am curious to why my JavaScript is functional inside the `cfscript` tag until calling the `setAttribute` method and why it is functional outside the `cfscript` tag.

I will appreciate your insight. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the **src** in **""**. Also, add the "**;**" at the end of **WriteOutput** closure. The below code should work for you.

```
<cfscript>
    WriteOutput('
    <script language = "JavaScript">
        var #ToScript(array, "jsArray")#
        var agent = jsArray[0];
        document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = agent.firstname + " " + agent.lastname;
        var imgurl = "_images/agentphoto.jpg";
        var node = document.createElement("LI");  
        var imgnode = (document.createElement("IMG"));
        imgnode.setAttribute("src", "imgurl");
        node.appendChild(imgnode);
        document.getElementById("agent_photo_list").appendChild(node);
    </script>
    ');
</cfscript>
```